# How to add headers in salesforce HTTP Callout Flow

Tags: salesforce

I have created one salesforce HTTP callout Flow referring POSMAN collection that my colleague gave me. when I debug it, it gives the following error.

```
Callout failed for invocable action testexternalservice.testaction. Expected declared response media type application/json, but got application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8; type=feed for operation testaction and service testexternalservice
```

I understand it as that the response should be in JSON and not in XML. Maybe HTTP callout by default gives a response in the XML. so, get the response in JSON I try to add **Accept:application/json** in the request header but not finding any option to add it. How can I do that?